# Conectar Alexa con mysql

Tags: nodejs, alexa

Muy buenas! Necesito conectar Alexa a una base de datos mysql, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. 
Este es el código que tengo de momento para la conexión, pero al iniciar la skill, me da error.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "host",
      user: "user",
      password: "pass",
      port: 3306
    });
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      speakOutput = 'Connected';
    });
```

Y esta es la salida a la hora de hacer el test:

```
Se ha producido un error con la respuesta de la Skill que has pedido
```

Package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "alexa utility for quickly building skills",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Amazon Alexa",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ask-sdk-core": "^2.6.0",
    "ask-sdk-model": "^1.18.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.326.0",
    "mysql": "^2.5.4",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^10.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Es correcta tu configuración? ¿Son correctas tus credenciales? Todo parece conforme a la [documentación](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html), excepto que no indicas el puerto.

Comment: Si, las credenciales son correctas. Ya he puesto el puerto y sigue sin funcionar.
Lo único que se me ocurre es que tenga mal el package.json, edito la pregunta y lo pongo ahí a ver si hay algo mal.

Comment: ¿`express: ^10.3.1`? Pero si la versión 5 aún está en `alfa`. Revisa eso también. Esa versión no me parece válida. Por otro lado, si usas Express 4.16.x o superior, no necesitas `body-parser`, ya que viene [incluido](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html). Saludos

Comment: Yo ando igual, según yo, creo no hay mucho soporte para mysql, si no más bien, consumir rest api, no sé si has intentado con dynamoBD ?

Comment: @SergioCastro lo que me fallaba, es que tenia que abrir el puerto en mi servidor. Saludos